# Authentication with Google Calendar API using Server Account and PHP

Tags: php, api, google-calendar-api

I'm struggling with this one: I am trying to create an event in a Google Calendar from a PHP script, using a Service Account.

Here’s what I’ve done:

- Created a Google Cloud Project
- Enabled the Calendar API
- Created an OAuth 2.0 Service Account, with Client ID, Email address and Public Key
- Downloaded the keyfile and saved this in my website
- Shared my Calendar with the Email address created in the Service Account (with Manage Sharing rights)

And here is my code:

```
<?php

require_once 'google_api_src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google_api_src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

const CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com';

// Make sure you keep your key.p12 file in a secure location, and isn't
// readable by others.
const KEY_FILE = 'google_api_src/xxxxxxxxx-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Hall Booking");

session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

// Load the key in PKCS 12 format
$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);

$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME,
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"),
    $key));

$service = new Google_CalendarService($client);

//Save token in session
if ($client->getAccessToken())
{
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}  

?>
```

I have debugged the code as far as I can, but the token is always set to null after the call to SetAssertionCredentials.  There are no PHP errors.

Any idea what is wrong, or how to debug further please?
Do I have to make any changes to config.php in the api src folder (I haven’t so far)?
Is the Application Name important?  What’s it used for?

Answer (score 1):

OK - so it turns out that the above code is working fine.  My misunderstanding was in thinking that the Google_CalendarService performed the authentication.  In fact, the authentication is only performed when an actual call to the calendar is made (such as insert Event).

However, I think that saving the token in the session is in the wrong place - it should be after an action has been performed.

To answer my other questions: No, you don't have to make any changes to config.php.  The Application Name can be set to anything (but I don't know what it's used for).

One other problem I came across:  I was creating an event using a calendar ID of 'primary'.  This sent back a success message, but I could not see the event in the calendar (I only have one calendar for that account).  It was only when I changed 'primary' to 'mycalendarid@gmail.com' that it started working.  Sounds like a bug in the API to me?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the demo: http://amazewebs.com/demo

Or get 1-to-1 help on this: http://amazewebs.com/go-premium

I have gotten this working with a service account, you are using the wrong URL in your code, or at least I have it working with no problems with my method...

See my code here: http://amazewebs.com

Or here:

```
<!-- language: php -->

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once '../google-api/Google_Client.php';
require_once '../google-api/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php';

session_start();

const CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR-CLIENT-ID-HERE>.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME = '<YOUR-SERVICE-EMAIL-HERE>@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
const KEY_FILE = '<YOUR-FINGERPRINT-HERE>-privatekey.p12';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("<PUT-YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-HERE");
$client->setUseObjects(true); //IF USING SERVICE ACCOUNT (YES)


if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
$client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

/* This next snippet of code is commonly written wrong, be sure to use the correct URL specified as below: */

$key = file_get_contents(KEY_FILE);
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setAssertionCredentials(new Google_AssertionCredentials(
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME, 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<YOUR-CALENDAR-ID-HERE-WITHOUT-THE-TRAILING"@group.calendar.google.com">/private/full/',
$key)
);

$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);
$event = new Google_Event();
$event->setSummary('<PUT-AN-EVENT-TITLE-HERE-OR-PASSED-VARIABLE>');
$event->setLocation('<PUT-A-LOCATION-HERE-OR-PASSED-VARIABLE>');

...The Full script can be found @ AmazeWebs.com
```

& Also I recommend **downloading the older google api library** as it doesn't seem to work with their latest 0.6.7!

...I have downloaded and packaged all the files in the correct path structure for you: http://amazewebs.com/downloads/google-api.zip

Alternatively, you can download every individual file and package it yourself if you want to download it from google directly:
http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/

Good luck :)

Comment: <YOUR-CALENDAR-ID-HERE>@group.calendar.google.com
What is calendar id?
I passed my email id in calendar id it does not work.
Please help.

Comment: I have explained this in full via videos and help documents. http://amazewebs.com/go-premium